# NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType queue is null

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a NSManagedObjectContext stacked like this:

```
 - (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
        if (_managedObjectContext != nil )
        {
           return _managedObjectContext;
        }

        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
       if (coordinator != nil)
       {
            NSManagedObjectContext* masterContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
            masterContext.undoManager = nil;
            [masterContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

            NSManagedObjectContext* mainContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
            mainContext.parentContext = masterContext;
            mainContext.undoManager = nil;

            NSManagedObjectContext* workerContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
            workerContext.parentContext = mainContext;
            workerContext.undoManager = nil;

            _managedObjectContext = workerContext;
        }
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }
```

I am using this context everywhere to read/write on objects of type NSManagedObject.

Here is the save method which is recursive in nature and saves the changes

```
+ (void) saveManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext withCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL, NSError *))completion
{
       NSLog(@"\nout current queue: %@",[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]);
       [managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"\ninside current queue: %@ current thread: %@",[NSOperationQueue currentQueue],[NSThread currentThread]);
        NSError *error  = nil;

        if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]){
            completion(NO, error);
        } else {
            if ([managedObjectContext parentContext] != nil){
            [self saveManagedObjectContext:[managedObjectContext parentContext] withCompletion:completion];
            } else {
                completion(YES, error);
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

But my app UI gets freeze every time the `saveManagedObjectContext:` method is called.

Moreover the NSLog statements gives unusual output:

```
out current queue: <NSOperationQueue: 0x15c527680>{name = 'NSOperationQueue Main Queue'}
inside current queue: (null) current thread: <NSThread: 0x15c6a86d0>{number = 4, name = (null)}
```

Why `current queue` is null?
Why my app is freezing or main thread is being blocked ?

Comment: What does the completion block that's passed into `saveManagedObjectContext` do?  (Also, if you pause your app in the debugger when it freezes, you can see what's happening on the main queue/thread in the Debug Navigator.)

Comment: The current queue isn't null, it just doesn't have a name.

Comment: @TomHarrington I just checked its pointer and its pointing to 0x0 i.e nowhere.

Comment: @PhillipMills completion block is doing absolutely nothing.